# tor - Not able to create single hop circuit (one hop tunnel)

Tags: tor

I follow the toctrl explain (http://www.thesprawl.org/research/tor-control-protocol/) on how to create really fast one hop circuits , i success to create circuit of one , but i didnt success to use firefox with tor after doing this.

i also try to use in "tor auto circuit project" , but i got error from tor that he didnt able to connect to node (each time different node), so he give up.

i also try to download the tortunnel project , but i didnt success to compile it.

Does any one has experience with this?

Thank you

Comment: This about change Tor code , so its belong to here.

Comment: did you make any progress with it?

Comment: No, sorry i didnt find solution

Answer (score 1):

Tor relays reject single hop circuits unless specifically allowed via the `AllowSingleHopExits` option in their torrc. Tor is an anonymity network, not a pool of single hop proxies. If you don't care about your anonymity then you should direct your traffic through a shell server somewhere.

Comment: The reason we are trying to use Tor as a proxy tool is because we don't have another proxy tool, built into a browser, which lets you choose a country, and keep switching IPs, and is no-cost. When that happens we'll stop abusing Tor.

Comment: Is it abuse? The more people using the exit nodes (and the system more generally), the harder those needing anonymity are to track.  That said, try building a 2-node circuit and ensuring that either the 2 nodes are in the same country or that the first node is in your country.  One sneaky thing you might be able to do is setup a local relay and use that as your guard node.  It won't get rid of the encryption overhead, but it will stop a second node from bottlenecking your connection to the exit and reduce latency.